# Is there such a thing as a "small slam" in baseball (or other sports)?

Tags: terminology, international-sports

In bridge, a "grand slam" means taking 13 tricks (out of a possible 13). A "small slam" means taking 12 tricks (all but one).

In baseball, a grand slam means a four-run homer (that clears the bases). Is there such a term as "small slam" (or other term) for a three-run homer (other than "three run homer" itself)?

In tennis, a "Grand Slam" refers to winning all four major events (Wimbleton, plus the Australian, French and U.S. Opens)? Would a "small slam" refer to "three out of four?"

How about in other sports?

Comment: In golf, a "grand slam" is winning each major championship (Masters, US Open, British Open, PGA Championship) in a calendar year.

Comment: @edmastermind29: Why not make this an answer? I did not know this.

Comment: Because you are asking about "small slams" which, to my knowledge, is not terminology used in golf. However, a "Tiger slam" is winning four consecutive majors over the span of two calendar years, and an "American slam" is winning the Masters, US Open, and PGA Championship in a calendar year. Note that these terms are informal yet widely-used.

Comment: @edmastermind29: It looks like an "American slam" would be a "small slam" in golf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "[Grand Slam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_slam)" is used often in various sports to refer to a specific difficult achievement in that sport.  If I'm not mistaken, its use in contract bridge is the original use of the term.

Occasionally, the term "small slam" is used in sports; for example, the [Winston Million](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Million) prize in NASCAR, which awarded a $1 Million prize for winning three out of the four major races, which they called a small slam.  I've never heard of the term "small slam" being used in baseball, but I would think that it could be applied to any situation where someone is "one" short of achieving a grand slam.

Comment: Is a "grand slam" in competitive eating a menu item at Denny's?

Comment: @edmastermind29 There aren't nearly enough questions on this site about the sport of competitive eating.

Comment: [Good point](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3474/in-which-ways-does-drinking-gallons-of-water-prepare-one-for-a-competitive-eatin)