# In which ways does drinking gallons of water prepare one for a competitive eating contest?

Tags: technique, training, competitive-eating

[Nathan's Hot Dog Eating Contest](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/hotdog-eating-champ-joey-chestnut-581152) winner Joey Chestnut quotes the [following](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/hotdog-eating-champ-joey-chestnut-581152):

> "I’ve slowly made my body adapt and understand what’s going to
>   happen," Chestnut said about the repetition of his training sessions,
>   which sees him fast for three days and **drink gallons of water before
>   binging in a practice contest**.

I assume drinking gallons of water makes room for more food, but I would think the water would displace any room made until released from the body.

**In which ways does drinking gallons of water prepare one for a competitive eating contest?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as water training.

Training with water far before an eating competition is very common. The act of chugging a gallon of water quickly over a long period of time will indeed stretch your stomach. If the competitor does this regularly before a competition, it will help him/her fit more food in their stomach.

As a side note, this is not recommended by doctors as it is very dangerous. Drinking a large amount of water in a short period of time can dilute the electrolytes in your blood, which can lead to a loss of heart, muscle and brain function.

Quotes from competitors on water training...

> "Lerman, 42, says he trains every day to stay in top shape. Like most
>   competitive eaters, he drinks massive amounts of water, more than a
>   gallon at a time, to stretch his stomach. Only rookies think that
>   fasting helps."

---

> "Champion eater Eric "Badlands" Booker, who has been training by
>   drinking 4-1/2 litres of water in three minutes, twice a day, for two
>   weeks.'It helps elasticate the stomach.'"

[Source](http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=111506) [Source](http://www.howstuffworks.com/competitive-eating1.htm)