# Does water training help with competitive eating speed?

Tags: training, competitive-eating

I entered a 2 pound burger eating contest and I've been researching water training. Water training helps with stretching the stomach to consume more in capacity, but I'm curious if water training also helps with the speed in which I eat since the quickest to eat the 2 pound burger wins.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't believe competitive eating counts as a "sport" as defined in the [help].

Comment: This question seams related: [In which ways does drinking gallons of water prepare one for a competitive eating contest?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/3474)

Answer (score 0):

Water training, by itself, does not improve speed in eating.

Preparation within 24 hours before the competition is key:

- Max out how much you can eat
- Drink water an hour after maxing out
- Wake up 6 hours before your competition and
- Drink water and have a liquid meal replacement

I haven't done an eating competition in years, but I was usually faster because I had confidence that I could eat more. In my experience, knowing I can eat more meant I could eat faster but YMMV.